# How to get the receipt_url in Square Connect V2

Tags: square-connect

I found the instructions to get the receipt_url in Version 1 of of Connect but I cannot find how to get the receipt_url for Connect Version 2 from a transaction. Where can we find that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no `receipt_url` currently in Connect V2 APIs. If you have a `transaction_id`, you can retrieve said transaction, and then the `tender` object (in the `tenders` array) will have an `id` which corresponds to a Connect V1 Payment (so you could use the `tender_id` with `RetrievePayment` as the `payment_id`).

References:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-transaction

Comment: Is there a C# client libary for Version 1?

Comment: Our C# SDK provides functionality for both Connect V1 and V2: https://github.com/square/connect-csharp-sdk/
For instance, the `receipt_url` shows up in the `V1Payment` (https://github.com/square/connect-csharp-sdk/blob/master/docs/V1Payment.md).

Comment: I was able to get it working, sort of, until I got this:


Name
Value
Type

jsonerror
"Error calling RetrievePayment: {\"type\":\"bad_request\",\"message\":\"Sandbox authorizations are not supported for this endpoint\"}"
string

I guess I have to use a "real" transaction?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. All V1 endpoints are not available in sandbox-mode, unfortunately. If you're just wanting to test the `receipt_url`, then I suggest doing a $1.00 transaction, and doing a refund afterward.

Comment: We are calling Charge in the v2 api and then immediately calling RetrievePayment in the v1 api but the RetrievePayment does not get the receipt_url.  it works in the debugger but not in real-time. Could this be a timing issue whereas the v1 api does not see the transaction for a certain period of time?

Comment: Sounds like it. There is a small delay between calling `Charge` and being able to retrieve said transaction. From our docs: "While Charge returns results immediately, there is a slight delay between processing the transaction and the information being available in RetreiveTransaction or ListTransactions."